# Scrolling horizontally in the tableview along with normal vertical scroll

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios4, uiscrollview, tableview

I have a requirement which lists the Cricket players in a table view with thier names and their stats like the following

> Name    total   4's 6's 1's average
>  
>   Tendulkar   231 O   6   5   3.6
>   Gangully    212 9   0   8   4.5

the total number of stats is like 8 to 10 , for that I have to make the stats horizantally scrollable, freezing the name. Can anyone explain me how to acheive this in a table view for iPhone sdk.

My question is, is it possible to scroll horizontally in the tableview freezing a single column, Please help me with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Technically it's possible. You need to make `UIScrollView` a subview in your `UITableViewCell`. Configure the scrollview to scroll only horizontally. Put data in it & set the content size...

Not sure about the performance implications of this on your tableView (vertical) scroll. This depends on the data in your horizontal scroll...

Comment: I have seen application that have sections and the horizontal scroll happens only for that section when scrolled, all the cells under that section's content can be scrolled horizontally at same time.

Comment: Fantasy Monster application, its NFL fantasy football application. if you have yahoo fantasy football account you can check that out. cant post image but here is the link http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fantasy-football-monster-11/id452523950?mt=8

Comment: yes, its possible that's what i wrote. What's the problem here?

Comment: What I meant is, by adding the UI scrollview as subview to UITableViewCell, can you achieve the section vise horizantal scrolling?